# Streaming music over WebRTC cutting in and out

Tags: webrtc, streaming, buffer, audio-streaming, screensharing

We would like to be able to play music in another tab (say YouTube, Spotify, Soundcloud, etc) and then stream that over a WebRTC connection to other peers.

We are doing this through the screenshare and it's mostly working, but the music will sometimes cut in and out for the listeners, giving it a choppy sound.  In other words, it sounds smooth to the person sending it (ie sharing it from the originating URL), but it sounds choppy to the on the receiving side of the WebRTC connection.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?  Is this a buffering issue?  If so, is it more likely buffering on the sending or the receiving side?

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC favors low latency over quality, with the goal of ensuring you can have normal speech communication.  To do this, a lot of things happen to your audio:

- Playback rate is constantly changed.  If playback gets behind, the rate speeds up.  If it's too far ahead, it slows down.
- There is a *very* small buffer, creating more opportunities for the playback buffer run dry.
- If packets are lost, the audio for their time is simply discarded... skipped over.  Playback isn't likely to buffer a bit and then continue.
- When audio is lost, a bit of a trail-off is synthesized.  This is fine for speech, but sounds bad for music.

On the media capture end, there are also audio "enhancements" designed for dealing with bad webcam microphones which can sometimes be applied to other mediastreams if configured incorrectly.  These include:

- Echo cancellation
- Noise reduction
- Automatic gain control

Finally, it's usually the case that audio bitrates are quite low by default.  You'll usually have to munge the SDP if you want stereo high quality audio.

All this to say, WebRTC might not be the right choice for you if you are concerned with quality.  I often resort to the MediaRecorder API.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  Great to know regarding WebRTC.

Would MediaRecorder API allow me to stream the audio to other peers?  From the online documentation, it sounds like it's just for recording audio; am I misreading that?

Also, would I be able to record the audio and stream it back out at the same time?  Or would I first need to finish recording a track to them stream it?

Comment: @Leo There isn't a convenient way to stream to other peers.  You have to set the MediaRecorder to output every second or two, then take these chunks and distribute somehow.  You could send this data over a WebRTC peer data connection.  This introduces a lot of latency and headache, but you'll have better quality audio.

Comment: So essentially I'd be manually creating a larger buffer on the sending side at the expense of latency.  But what about on the receiving side?  What if the issue is that the buffer isn't big enough on the receiving side?

Comment: On the receiving side, you buffer, and playback as you can.  I haven't checked recently if MediaRecorder's output will work with MediaSource Extensions... but that's the easiest method, if it does work.  What I've done in the past is done some work server-side, and played it back on the receiving end with a simple `<video>` tag that pointed at a Node.js server.

Comment: Sorry, not fully following. If I'm using WebRTC to stream it, then on the receiving side I wouldn't be able to control the buffer (at least from what I understand).  So how would I buffer on the receiving side - use MedaRecorder again to record small 1-2 second chunks and play it back?

Side question - what about using Web Audio API instead of WebRTC to send the audio to peers?